# Keep different groups on the same page in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2016. I have got a report with subreports of which the following are my subreports of interest for this question:

resultFormat8 - which is a crosstab report.

resultFormat1 - which is not a crosstab report - and THIS IS THE ONE i DO NOT WANT DATA split between different groups on various pages. I guess it is splitting because the subreport is grouped by TEST.TEST_NUMBER. How can i get all the results to show on one page and only move over to the next page only if there is not enough space.

Currently even if one group has just 2 rows of data, the next group starts in a new page essentially wasting almost the whole page.
The relevant subreport is grouped by TEST.TEST_NUMBER - and hence data for each TEST_NUMBER starts on a new page.

I have tried the following:
In the Section Expert, turn off 'Keep Together' for the section that the subreport is in.
Within the subreport, turn off 'Keep Together' from Group Expert for the Test_Number group

None of the above has helped.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Geeta

Answer (score 0):

The Keep Together check boxes in the sections won't work to keep groups together.  To do this you need to change the Group Options settings.  Here is how to do this in Crystal Reports 2016.  There are 2 ways to do it.

Option 1

1. Open Group Expert by clicking "Report" > "Group Expert" on the File Menu Bar.
2. Select the appropriate group by field in the right panel of the Group Expert window.
3. Click the "Options" button found on the lower left corner of the Group By panel to open the Change Group Options window.
4. Click on the "Options" tab in the Change Group Options window.
5. Check the "Keep Group Together" check box.

Option 2

1. While in the Design View of the report, right click on the Group Header for the group you want to keep together.  Then click on "Change Group".  This will open the Change Group Options window.
2. Click on the "Options" tab in the Change Group Options window.
3. Check the "Keep Group Together" check box.